# Building ordered and limited delete request in jooq

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jooq

I recently encountered the following problem with buiding queries in jooq (version 3.1.0):

I want to build delete statement with order and limit constraints. So, my aim is to build something like this:
`DELETE FROM table ORDER BY field DESC LIMIT 1` (this is MySql syntax)

But i haven't found nesessary methods in result delete query object:

```
 DSLContext context = createContext();
 DeleteWhereStep delete = context.delete(createTable(table));
 DeleteConditionStep whereStep = delete.where(condition);
 whereStep.orderBy(...)//and no such method here
```

There are all nesessary methods in select statements and none for delete.
Is it possible to set order and limit for delete request in jooq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of jOOQ 3.2, these sorts of extensions are currently not implemented yet. Chances are, that [#203](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/203) could be implemented in jOOQ 3.3, though.

In the mean time, you have two options:

#### Resort to plain SQL

i.e. write something like:

```java
context.execute("DELETE FROM {0} ORDER BY {1} DESC LIMIT 1",
    createTable(table),
    field);
```

#### Manually transform your SQL statement into something equivalent

I suspect that the `ORDER BY .. LIMIT` extension to the MySQL `DELETE` statement is just sugar for:

```sql
DELETE FROM table t
WHERE t.id IN (
  SELECT id FROM table
  ORDER BY field LIMIT 1
)
```

Or with jOOQ:

```java
context.delete(TABLE)
       .where(TABLE.ID.in(
           select(TABLE.ID)
          .from(TABLE)
          .orderBy(TABLE.FIELD)
          .limit(1)
       ))
```

Comment: Thanks, solution with subrequest certainly works but I have limitations in available data while building request. I don't have information about table unique keys, just table name and nesessary fields with types and values (jooq is used for plain sql building).So, now I build normal select statement and manually replace _select_ part with _delete_. Hope to see nesessary methods in next versions.